# How to filter data frame by bottom 25% , top 25% and 50% using quantile?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I filter the data using quantile by value? Top 25%, bottom 25%, 50%

| Gene | FPKM |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0.34 |
| D | 0.25 |
| C | 0.75 |
| E | 1.5 |
| B | 0.31 |
| F | 2.45 |
| Y | 7.89 |

Out Put:

Top 25% would be 1.75 ~2

| Gene | FPKM |
| --- | --- |
| Y | 7.89 |
| F | 2.45 |

So far what I've tried:

```
q75 = df['q0_FPKM'].quantile(q=0.75)
df[df['q0_FPKM'].ge(q75)] # 75th quantile

q50 = df['q0_FPKM'].quantile(q=0.50)
df[df['q0_FPKM'].ge(q50)] # 50th quantile
```

Not sure how I can do bottom 25 percentile... or even this is the correct way to filter.

Comment: Can you add expected ouput from sample data?

Comment: use `np.percentile`?

Comment: Just edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html),
[`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
s = df['FPKM'].quantile([0.25,0.75])
print (s)
0.25    0.325
0.75    1.975
Name: FPKM, dtype: float64

df1 = df[df['FPKM'].ge(s[0.75])]
print (df1)
  Gene   FPKM
5    F   2.45
6    Y   7.89

df2 = df[df['FPKM'].le(s[0.25])]
print (df2)
  Gene   FPKM
1    D   0.25
4    B   0.31

df3 = df[df['FPKM'].between(s[0.25], s[0.75], inclusive=False)]
print (df3)
  Gene   FPKM
0    A   0.34
2    C   0.75
3    E   1.50
```

Comment: for df2 should it be .ge not .le?
if I'm reading command for df3 correctly, that's for 50% correct?

Comment: Ok so .le(s[0.25]) is for bottom 25th percentile?